# From where I can get the SQL SERVER database file?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010, export

I have opened a `VB.NET` application solution by the `Visual Studio 2010` and I want to get the database file that contains the tables , queries , views ... etc, in order to export it to the `SQL SERVER STUDIO` and work on it.
How can I do this ?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

check this below file url:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data

From there you can get your user databases and their log files too.

Comment: What I meant exactly is : get the database file (or files idk) from the application files not from the server files.